# Not entering into onClick() or onLongPress() of GridView + android

Tags: android, gridview, onclicklistener

- I have a GridView.
- I am setting adapter to it.
- Adding setOnClickListener() and setOnLongClickListener().

**Issue :**

- Sometimes it enters into setOnLongClickListener()
- Sometimes in setOnClickListener() and
- Sometimes in none.

public class ABCAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
...

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
ViewHolder holder = null;
    final Answer option = mOptionsList.get(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(mLayoutId, null);
        holder.data = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.data);
        holder.row = (LinearLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.row);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (OptionViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.data.setText("Data");
    holder.row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(final View selectionView) {
        ...
        }
    });
    holder.row.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        ...
        return false;
        }
    });
}
```

...

}

Comment: post your code here... what you have done ?

Comment: @NehaC You'll get response as soon as you post your code here.

Answer (score 0):

try
`gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()`

from your activity that has the gridView

Answer (score 0):

`return true` from both onClick() and onLongClick() method

```
@Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        ...
        return true;
        }

@Override
        public void onClick(final View selectionView) {
        ...
return true;
        }
```

Alternate solution
Use following listeners in your gridview

```
mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
mGridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
```